# Replacing solution NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have an equation that I solve :

```
 sol = NDSolve[{  Div[(1 - f[x]) Grad[f[x], {x, y}, "Polar"], {x, y}, 
"Polar"] == -(1 - f[x]) f[x] (f[x] - 0.8), f[1] == 0.7, f'[0.00001] == 0.0001}, f, 
{x, 0.0001, 1}]
```

I want to plot the function : $(1-f(x))f'(x)/f(x)$.
How can I do it simply, meaning, by replacing the interpolating function by a function.
I do not want to do :

```
Plot[1-InterpolatingFunction[..][x]...]
```

because it is too long, and not easy to handle if I change the equation.

I tried :

```
f[x]/.sol[[1]]
Plot[(1-f[x])f'[x]/f[x],{x,0.0001,1}]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: [This knowledge base article](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505) should help. If you need additional help, read through other questions on this site - there are countless questions on this exact topic (maybe not for `NDSolve` specifically, but for `Solve`, `NSolve` and related functions - and they all work the same in terms of using their output)

Comment: In addition, your code example does not evaluate because the definition for `alpha` is missing. People, in general, are more likely to help if they have a working minimal example. You can simply edit your question and add what you use for `alpha`.

Comment: Also might want to use `NDSolveValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Daniel Lichtblau, I recommend using `NDSolveValue` rather than `NDSolve`, because it returns the interpolation function directly.

```
Clear[f]
f = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {Div[(1 - f[x]) Grad[f[x], {x, y}, "Polar"], {x, y}, "Polar"] == 
       -(1 - f[x]) f[x] (f[x] - 0.8), 
     f[1] == 0.7,
     f'[0.00001] == 0.0001},
    f, {x, 0.0001, 1}];
g[x_] = (1 - f[x]) f'[x]/f[x];
Plot[g[x], {x, 0.0001, 1}]
```

[image: plot]